# Is there a way to see how deep I am?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a way to see how deep a hole I've dug in Minecraft, besides counting the number of squares I've dug through? I realize at some point there is bedrock so if I can't see how far down I am, can I see how far from the bedrock I am?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can view your distance from the bedrock layer by pressing F3, which will show your current coordinates on screen. This isn't quite the same as knowing how far you are from the *surface*, but it's a good way to get a quick estimate of how deep you are.

[image: Screenshot]

Before the F3 feature was added, the best way to estimate your vertical position in the world was to pay attention to [what kind of ore you find as you dig](https://minecraft.wiki/w/File:PercentOfOreByHeight.png). (This is still very useful knowledge to have, for obvious reasons.)

If you prefer not use F3 to get your exact coordinates and want a purely in-world solution, you should look to one of the other methods of tracking distance which [JavadocMD mentioned](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/10292/274).

Comment: I'd like to point out that the graph is inclusive rather than exclusive -- I've found coal directly above the bedrock, and iron below gold.

Comment: @Raven That's a good thing to point out -- You can find iron all the way down to bedrock, not just from 64-32 like the image is labeled.

Comment: Since when is lava found only in the bottom 10 layers?

Comment: I think it refers to wide open pools of lava as opposed to isolated springs, which can pop up all over the place.

Comment: This is most certainly outdated, Brant.

Comment: -1 for this new edit; even *if* it were true that `there's no way to determine exactly where other than counting by hand` *(which is false, see highest-rated answer)*, estimating by the frequencies of ore you come across is not a viable strategy - you'd need a sample-size of several thousand blocks to get an accurate estimate.  In that case, it would be *much* faster/easier to just tunnel back to the surface and count.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Fixed, I hope!

Comment: As a rule of thumb, I figure that unless I'm in an Extreme Hills biome (on the F3 screen as of 1.2), the surface is approximately between y= 60 and 70. It's not exact, though.

Comment: Also, the texture pack I'm using in that screenshot is [Tronic](http://evilmousestudios.com/tronic/).

Answer (score 29):

With current game version, hitting F3 will show your coordinates on the screen.
You can then find how deep you are by comparing the bottom coordinates to the surface coordinates.

Answer (score 18):

There's no easy way, as far as I know, you'll have to count.

I would suggest coming up with a system for reference. For example as you're digging down, you could place a distinctive block (one that wouldn't naturally be there, like cloth) every 10 vertical blocks traveled. Then it's easier to count later. Signs would also work, and then you wouldn't have to count 10s every time, just put the depth on the sign.

Comment: +1, I put a torch ever 5 steps, and a torch on both sides every 25.

Comment: -1 because F3 is (really) easy

Comment: @fireDude67 But some people may find it "cheating".

Comment: I like to place different colours of wool at given intervals down the shaft.  Works great, until you run out of colours.

Comment: You could count up from bedrock - the highest bedrock is level 5. Could be easier if you're going for a mine at level 12.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure some will object but there are also external mapper tools that can help with this kind of thing.  In particular, I've found [MCmap Live](http://mineville.net/2010/10/mcmap-live/) to be the simplest to use for this purpose because it has a slider that slices your map at any given level.  If you don't use a mac, try one of these: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Programs_and_Editors.

In practice, external mappers are much slower than just marking levels as others have suggested.
However, in cases where I'm confused or lost, it's a tool I'm not above using.  For instance, I recently found myself coming back from the Nether in a totally random underground location with almost no tools and I really needed to carefully plan my way up to the surface (to conserve my nearly spent diamond axe) or I was gonna end up punching through stone for hours.

Comment: Wow, MCmap is an awesome app. Thanks for pointing it out. :)

Answer (score 1):

The best to check your depth is to place torches, signs, wool, or iron, gold, diamond, or redstone blocks every 10 blocks or so. You can guess how far you are by the kind of blocks you've seen as well, but this is pretty iffy, as i've found iron and coal right before the bedrock. also, and this is only because you'd be mining, it's a good idea to have water with you or to have a 1*2 tunnel if you are tunnel mining.

I would put torches/signs every 5-10 blocks, and once you are at an adequate level for your desired ore, begin branch mining. but if you would rather, f3 is another good idea. the torch/signs method is a bit iffy because you might be doing it on an too high or low surface but i find that F3 can sometimes not work all that awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Make a stack of stairs. Count out as many as you need if you want to reach a specific level (leave the rest on a separate stack) or just keep the full stack if you want to measure.

Build stairs down either until you run out of stairs (then you reached your desired level) or to the bottom (and your level is 64-[remaining stairs].

While this may take longer than just counting, the time spent on placing the stairs will be saved on running up them instead of jumping - two birds with one stone.